# Where is the error message for a failed podcast download?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I am running iTunes 11 on Mountain Lion, and I am subscribed to several podcasts. All of them work except one: With that one, new episodes are found, but every time I try to download one I get an exclamation point next to the name. If I copy the URL from the episode and paste it into a browser, I can download the file so I don't know why iTunes is failing. Is there a way to see an error message? I looked in Console and did not see anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you are downloading episodes in iTunes 11, this icon shows up:

[image: iTunes downloading icon]

Click it and you can open your download progress:

[image: Download progress dialog]

If downloading fails, an error message will show up to the right of the status bar with an error code. You can Google this code for info. In my experience, this downloader is very unreliable if you have anything else downloading at the same time, or if you allow simultaneous downloads, although if you allow simultaneous downloads it generally finishes quicker if there are no errors.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am getting a 404 which I know is a "page not found" error. I believe the URL is correct, so the mystery deepens...

Comment: Maybe iTunes has an old cached version of the RSS feed and the old version has a broken link that has since been corrected. Thus you can download it manually from a browser. Have you tried unsubscribing and resubscribing?

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the podcast completely and then resubscribed. When I look at the rss.xml, I see 3 references to the url: in the tags `link`, `guid` and `enclosure`. The one in `enclosure` is not URL encoded and so has spaces within the URL instead of %20. The other two are fine. Do you know which one iTunes uses to do the download?

Comment: Can you put the RSS feed on pastebin or mediafire?

Comment: Here is the feed on paste bin: http://pastebin.com/WTXHE2rR